# ¿ Cómo incorporar busquedas con parametros usando Repository Hibernate y con paginación Page, en Java Spring contra BBDD de MySql?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, paginación

Buenos días / tardes,

Acabo de aprender a realizar paginación usando Repository en Java contra my BBDD MySQL. Para ello, básicamente en mi DAO uso el modelo y hago el cast a mi DTO.

```
/* obtener lista de todas las preguntas tabla PAGEABLE con mapeo incluido de page    */
public Page<PreguntaDTO> getAllPreguntasPorPagina(Pageable pageable){
  return preguntaRepository.findAll(pageable).map(PreguntaDTO::fromEntity);
}
```

Mi controlador recibe los parámetros para la paginación.

```
@GetMapping("/listadoPreguntasPaginadas")
public ResponseEntity<Page<PreguntaDTO>> listadoPreguntasPaginadas(
  @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page,
  @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") int size,
  @RequestParam(defaultValue = "pregunta") String order,
  @RequestParam(defaultValue = "true") boolean asc
  ) {
  Page<PreguntaDTO> preguntaDTOpaginada= preguntaService.listadoPreguntasPageables(PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by(order)));
  return new ResponseEntity<Page<PreguntaDTO>>(preguntaDTOpaginada, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Pero ahora necesito que tenga un parámetro de campo de texto y de id.
Me explico mejor.

Mi modelo es:

```
@Entity
@Table (name="preguntas")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class) // sin esto no genera fecha automatica
@Getter
@Setter
public class Pregunta implements Serializable  {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 5191280932150590610L;

  @Id // definimos clave primaria
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)  // que se genere de forma automatica y crezca
  private Long id;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @LastModifiedDate    
  private  Date createAt;   

  @NotBlank // que no este campo en blanco, validar documento
  @NotNull(message = "Nombre no puede ser nulo")
  private String pregunta;
  private Boolean activa=true;
  private Long deEnfermedadById;//ID de Enfermedad 
  private Long createdById;//ID de usuario 
  private Boolean denunciado=false; 
  private String aux="Campo auxiliar sin usar";
}
```

mi búsqueda, además de pageable, debe devolver solo aquellas preguntas que en su campo "pregunta" tengan una palabra o texto ( cadena `String`) y que además corresponda a un id de enfermedad ( campo : `deEnfermedadById` ) determinado.

Sa hacerlo usando Entity Management  "em" , pero con "em" no se hacer paginación. Pongo debajo método que uso para hacer las búsquedas con "em".

```
public List<Pregunta> listadoPreguntasByIdEnfermedad(Long idEnf, String cadena) {
  List<Pregunta> lista = new ArrayList<>();
  String sql = "select * from sanihelp.preguntas where "
                            + "de_enfermedad_by_id = ?";
  if (cadena != null) {
    sql = sql.concat(" and pregunta like ? ");
  };
  try {
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
    int indice=1;
    query.setParameter(indice , idEnf);
    if (cadena != null) {
      query.setParameter(++indice, "%" + cadena + "%");
    }
    for (Object o : query.getResultList()) {
      Object[] objeto = (Object[]) o;
      Pregunta modelo = new Pregunta(); 
      modelo.setId(((BigInteger) objeto[0]).longValue());                                               modelo.setActiva(Boolean.getBoolean(String.valueOf(objeto[1])));
      modelo.setAux(String.valueOf(objeto[2]));
      modelo.setCreateAt((java.util.Date)objeto[3]);
      modelo.setCreatedById(((BigInteger) objeto[4]).longValue());
      modelo.setDeEnfermedadById(((BigInteger) objeto[5]).longValue());                     modelo.setDenunciado(Boolean.getBoolean(String.valueOf(objeto[6])));    
      modelo.setPregunta(String.valueOf(objeto[7]));        
      lista.add(modelo);
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("excepcion lanzada" + e);
  }
  return lista;
}
```

Como veis estoy en un poco atascado. Con Entity Management no se si es posible usar paginación y de ser posible como hacerse. Desde Respository con Hibernate, acabo de aprender pero con los métodos que veo ( son los básicos ) no se incorporar más parámetros de búsqueda.

Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia será bien recibida.

Muchas gracias

nota: en una respuesta se me indica no puse interface, lo añado.

```
package com.uned.project.sanitaUned.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.uned.project.sanitaUned.model.Pregunta;

@Repository
public interface PreguntaRepository extends JpaRepository<Pregunta, Long> {

}
```

este extiende de :

```
 */
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface JpaRepository<T, ID> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>, QueryByExampleExecutor<T> {
```

que a su vez extiende de pageable

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> extends CrudRepository<T, ID> {

    /**
     * Returns all entities sorted by the given options.
     *
     * @param sort
     * @return all entities sorted by the given options
     */
    Iterable<T> findAll(Sort sort);

    /**
     * Returns a {@link Page} of entities meeting the paging restriction provided in the {@code Pageable} object.
     *
     * @param pageable
     * @return a page of entities
     */
    Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

SOLUCION IMPLEMENTADA ( intento realizar como me indicáis en respuestas y no me funciona ).

```
@Repository
public interface PreguntaRepository extends JpaRepository<Pregunta, Long> {

/*  */ 

     @Query ("select * from sanihelp.preguntas where de_enfermedad_by_id = :de_enfermedad_by_id") 
     Page <Pregunta> findAllWithFields(Pageable pageable , @Param ("de_enfermedad_by_id")  long de_enfermedad_by_id );

}
```

Y al ejecutar en servidor me da error …..

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-04-07 18:16:44.091 ERROR 8424 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'preguntaController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'preguntaService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'preguntaService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'preguntaDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'preguntaDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'preguntaRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'preguntaRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.uned.project.sanitaUned.repository.PreguntaRepository.findAllWithFields(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,long)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 1):

El `like` de sql lo podés lograr agregando el query method con `Contains` a la interface del repositorio (que no la veo incluido en código de la pregunta):

El método a agregar debiera ser algo así, pero está el tema de que incluiste el "ById" como nombre del campo. Esto se supoerpone con la convención para escribir query methods y tal vez el método no funcione.

```
List<Pregunta> findAllByPreguntaContainsAndDeEnfermedadById(String texto, Long id);
```

Siempre tenés el recurso de agregar el query como annotation:

```
@Query("Select p from Pregunta where p.pregunta LIKE %:texto% and p.deEnfermedadById = %:id%")
List<Pregunta> findAllByPreguntaContainsAndDeEnfermedadById(String texto, Long id);
```

[Guia rápida](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-like-queries)
[Spring JPA reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods)

Comment: Gracias, pero no te entiendo. Como ves cuando uso PreguntaRepository me limito a extender la de Jpa. ( te lo añado a la pregunta) . Ahí veo como llego al pageable, pero no a uno con parámetros.

Comment: Gracias Juan. He tenido que aprender un poco más para darme cuenta de que tu ya me lo habías contestado todo. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias Juan por tu ayuda.
      Temo que por mi torpeza no supe entenderla del todo y un buen amigo del gremio Agustin Lidon Martinez tuvo que venir después de muchas horas de trabajo perdido ( o como dijo Edison, no he perdido el tiempo, ahora se mil formas de NO hacer una query bien) me enseño que hacía mal.

```
@Repository
public interface PreguntaRepository extends JpaRepository<Pregunta, Long> {

     @Query ("SELECT p FROM Pregunta p WHERE p.deEnfermedadById = :de_enfermedad_by_id") 
     Page <Pregunta> findAllWithFieldsContaining ( Pageable pageable,  @Param ("de_enfermedad_by_id")  Long   de_enfermedad_by_id  );  
}
```

Juan, me pusiste a un nivel de conocimiento que todavía no tengo, aunque ahora NO creo se me olvide. No supe distinguir entre búsqueda de SQL y de HQL.
- en la primera tu usas el select con el nombre de la tabla sanihelp.preguntas
- mientras que en HQL select usas el modelo Pregunta en el select.

Gracias mil JUAN y AGUSTIN.